# get current customer from admin section

Tags: admin, customer, sales-order

If I am on the admin section for creating manual orders and I have selected to use an existing customer rather than create a new one how can I access that customers details?

To clarify, by manual orders I mean by clicking - `Sales -> Orders -> Create New Order` and then selecting a customer to create an order for.

I'm hoping there is a function similar to the `Mage::registry` for products and categories so that I can select the customer email address within a template loaded via a custom module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customer is saved in session. Assuming you are on the order create page, you can retrieve it like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getCustomer();
```

Comment: perfect - thank you!

Comment: And for Magento 2?